# HTML Templating Engines and Liquid

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-engine, liquid

I'm trying to get my head round templating engines and if there is something suitable for my requirements.

I'd like to specify HTML and provide dynamic functionality from within the HTML itself. For example, say I had a check box on a page

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox"> This is my checkbox</label>
```

I'd like to specify logic within HTML so that I display more content only if that checkbox has been checked, e.g.

```
// if #cbox1.checked == true
    <h1>The check box is checked</h1>
// else
   <h1>The check box is not checked</h1>
// end
```

Now, it is likely that [liquid](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/115244038-an-overview-of-liquid-shopifys-templating-language) will be used to provide dynamic functionality based on a data store. So it'd also be nice to use the same liquid syntax to make the form dynamic (i.e. use liquid syntax in the if conditional above).

Is it possible to write a 'js engine', perhaps using jquery, that I could include in my web pages that would allow me to use liquid syntax but bind to variables in the 'js engine' as well as the data store to make my content dynamic?

Or, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Vue.js (https://vuejs.org/).

The template engine is very easy to learn, and provides all the functionality you mention.

Here is a working example of your scenario:

https://jsbin.com/kikaxecogo/edit?html,output

But all you need to do is initialise Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showData: false
  }
});
```

and write the template data:

```
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="showData">

 <div v-if="showData">
   This is visible using v-if
 </div>

 <div v-else>
    The check box is not checked
 </div>
```

I've written a introduction guide to Vue.js here https://steveedson.co.uk/vuejs-intro/

You can also bind to other text inputs, data from ajax sources etc:

```
<input type="text" v-model="name">

<p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
```

And everything will update automatically.

---

As an alternative to Vue.js, there is also:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/
- https://angularjs.org/

Comment: Yes. Looks promising: I was reviewing Angular but just felt I needed something more lightweight. Vue certainly looks simpler to use.

Comment: I personally think that Vue is excellent. It works very well for small examples like this, but can grow with the project and can be used for large scale web applications. Good luck!

Comment: I have been using angularjs last 4 years on a project and the support from open source developers is also strong and its very light weight and lot of things easily possible.